# get the newest value only from an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, angular9

I'm working with **Angular 9 / rxjs 6.5.2**,

I want to get only the latest value when I subscribe to the Observable, 
I want the **latest** and not the **last**, because for the last, it will wait until Observable completes but in my case I want the latest at this moment.

**My Code:**

PS: You can test it directly in this link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/pjreww

```js
const observable = new Observable(subscriber => {
  subscriber.next(1);
  subscriber.next(2);
  subscriber.next(3);
  setTimeout(() => {
    subscriber.next(4);
    subscriber.complete();
  }, 1000);
});

observable
  .pipe(
    //some pipe to make me take the latest value only
  )
  .subscribe({
    next(x) { console.log('got value ' + x); },
  });
```

**Output Wanted:**:

```
3
4
```

**Actual Output**

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shareReplay(1)` that will always replay only the latest value emitted:

```
observable
  .pipe(
    shareReplay(1),
  )
  .subscribe({
    next(x) { console.log('got value ' + x); },
  });
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/pjreww-fzs5sl?file=index.ts